# Calling C++ function having std::vectors as input and output parameters from Julia

Tags: c++, julia, std

I am new to Julia and and I am trying to access my C++ code from Julia. More precisely, I am trying to call a C++ function from Julia using Cxx. The input and output parameters of the C++ function are std::vectors, see the function compute_sum in the example below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector< int > compute_sum( const std::vector< std::vector<int> >& input )
{
    std::vector< int > resut( input.size() , 0 );
    for ( std::size_t i = 0 ; i != input.size() ; ++i )
    {
        for ( std::size_t j = 0 ; j != input[i].size() ; ++j )
        {
            resut[i] += input[i][j];
        }
    }
    return resut;
}

void simple_function( int i )
{
    std::cout << "The numbers is : " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Assuming this function is stored as code.cpp I am compiling it to a shared object code.so using:

```
 g++ -shared -fPIC code.cpp -o code.so
```

and as a result I obtain a file code.so

Having this, I run Julia in the same folder as code.so. My version of Julia is 0.6.2. Then I import Cxx and the code.so file using:

```
julia> using Cxx
julia> const path_to_lib = pwd()
julia> addHeaderDir(path_to_lib, kind=C_System)
julia> Libdl.dlopen(path_to_lib * "/code.so", Libdl.RTLD_GLOBAL)
Ptr{Void} @0x00000000044bda30
julia> cxxinclude("code.cpp")
```

In odder to test if the process is successful I am calling the simple_function and obtain the correct results:

```
julia> @cxx simple_function(1234)
The numbers is : 1234
```

Then I want to call compute_sum function. For that I need somehow to create, or convert Julia vector into C++ std::vector< std::vector >. I am trying the following:

```
julia> cxx" std::vector< std::vector<int> > a;"
true
julia> icxx" a.push_back( std::vector<int>(1,2) ); "
julia> icxx" a.push_back( std::vector<int>(1,3) ); "
julia> icxx" a.push_back( std::vector<int>(1,4) ); "
julia> icxx" a.size(); "
0x0000000000000003
```

So I assume that the vector is created in a correct way. Then I trying to call the function with it, but I fail:

```
julia> @cxx compute_sum(a)
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined
julia> @cxx compute_sum("a")
ERROR: Got bad type information while compiling Cxx.CppNNS{Tuple{:compute_sum}} (got String for argument 1)
julia> icxx " compute_sum(a);"
ERROR: syntax: extra token """ after end of expression
```

Could anyone help me please with the following question(s):

1. How to call compute_sum function from Julia? I am happy to use any technique (not necessary Cxx) that works and is reasonably fast.
2. How to convert the result of compute_sum to Julia array?

Thank you very much!

pawel

Comment: "I am compiling it to a static library using:

 `g++ -shared -fPIC code.cpp -o code.so`" - there's some confusion here. You *say* you build a *static* library, but the `-shared` compiler option says otherwise. Also, static libraries are usually named with a ".a" extension while ".so" is for shared libraries ("so" being short for "shared object"). So, what do you *actually* mean to do?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I did mean shared object. Changed the line to: "I am compiling it to a shared object code.so using". Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: For what purpose will you be using this for? Is it like the row sums of a matrix, or are the `vector`s inside `input` allowed to have different `size`s? Plus, you seem to have a small glitch in your code --- the inner loop is also incrementing `i`. Is this intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use the `icxx` string macro, this allows interpolating Julia variables using `$`. Here is a full example:

```
using Cxx

cxx"""
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> compute_sum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &input)
{
  std::vector<int> result(input.size(), 0);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != input.size(); ++i)
  {
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j != input[i].size(); ++j) // corrected to ++j here
    {
      result[i] += input[i][j];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
"""

cxx_v = icxx"std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1,2},{1,2,3}};"
println("Input vectors:")
for v in cxx_v
  println("  ", collect(v))
end

cxx_sum = icxx"compute_sum($cxx_v);"
println("Cxx sums: $(collect(cxx_sum))")
```

Running this in Julia should print:

```
Input vectors:
  Int32[1, 2]
  Int32[1, 2, 3]
Cxx sums: Int32[3, 6]
```

To do this using a shared library, create `vector.hpp` like this:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> compute_sum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &input);
```

`vector.cpp`:

```
#include "vector.hpp"

std::vector<int> compute_sum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &input)
{
     // same as before
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o libvector.so vector.cpp
```

In Julia:

```
using Cxx

const path_to_lib = pwd()
addHeaderDir(path_to_lib, kind=C_System)
Libdl.dlopen(joinpath(path_to_lib, "libvector"), Libdl.RTLD_GLOBAL)
cxxinclude("vector.hpp")

cxx_v = icxx"std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1,2},{1,2,3}};"
println("Input vectors:")
for v in cxx_v
  println("  ", collect(v))
end

cxx_sum = icxx"compute_sum($cxx_v);"
println("Cxx sums: $(collect(cxx_sum))")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one more question. This solution work when a function compute_sum is given in Julia. However, when I am trying to call a function from a precompiled shared object, I am getting an segmentation fault:

julia> icxx"compute_sum($cxx_v);"

signal (11): Segmentation fault
while loading no file, in expression starting on line 0
unknown function (ip: 0x7f4fa27de7d9)
unknown function (ip: 0x7f4fa27de6db)
unknown function (ip: 0x7f4fa27de6bc)

Do you happen to know if this can be fixed?

Comment: I have updated the answer, you need a separate header and also make sure the second ++i is changed to ++j, that gives a segfault too.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what i need. Now I have two working solutions. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are willing to work on Julia *arrays*, I assume that you would like to work on *matrices*, *i.e.*, arrays having constant lengths in the dimensions. For this reason, I would suggest you do not use `vector`s of `vector`s, but instead use just `vector`s. Then, you should remember that Julia uses **column-major** arrays, whereas in C/C++, the memory layout is **row-major**.

Below, you can find a templated version of your code using iterators. This way, you can compile `compute_sum` for use in C++ with your favourite `std::vector`s. Or else, you can ask your compiler to generate the appropriate code with pointers, to be able to use with other languages, such as Julia.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <class RandomIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt compute_sum(const std::uint64_t nrows, RandomIt xbegin, RandomIt xend,
                     OutputIt rbegin) {
  const std::size_t ncols{std::distance(xbegin, xend) / nrows};
  typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIt>::value_type sum{0};
  for (std::size_t row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
    for (std::size_t col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
      sum += xbegin[col * nrows + row];

    *rbegin++ = sum;
    sum = 0;
  }
  return rbegin;
}

/* you can use the above code in your C++ applications as follows */
// int main() {
//   std::vector<int> matrix{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
//                           6, 7, 8, 9}; /* 3x3 matrix in column-major */
//   std::vector<int> result(3);
//   compute_sum(3, std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix), std::begin(result));
//   return 0;
// }

/* or, ask your compiler to generate code with C linkage (no name mangling) */
extern "C" {
void compute_sum(const std::uint64_t m /* use fixed-size integers */,
                 const std::uint64_t n /* use fixed-size integers */,
                 const std::int64_t *xbegin /* use fixed-size integers */,
                 std::int64_t *rbegin /* use fixed-size integers */) {
  compute_sum(m, xbegin, xbegin + m * n, rbegin);
}
}
```

then, compile the code as usual:

```sh
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -fPIC -shared code.cpp -o code.so
```

Then, use Julia's [capabilities](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/) to call the compiled C code:

```
const libhandle = Libdl.dlopen(joinpath(pwd(), "code.so"))
const funhandle = Libdl.dlsym(libhandle, :compute_sum)

function compute_sum(A::Matrix{Int64})
    result = Vector{Int64}(size(A, 1))
    ccall(funhandle, Void, (UInt64, UInt64, Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64}),
          size(A, 1), size(A, 2), A, result)
    return result
end

result = compute_sum(ones(Int64, 5, 6)) # prints Int64[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much! That certainly help and make my example work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank Arda Aytekin and Bart Janssens for their great help and suggestions. Both solutions works perfectly and I would like to mark them both as an answer to my question, but it seems I can only mark one answer...
In the next days I will run speed comparison test to see if one the solution which is based on pure C interface is faster or not to the one using Cxx. I will update you once this is ready.

Comment: Solutions are not comparable to each other. My solution uses fixed dimension lengths and uses contiguous iterators, whereas Bart's solution uses arrays of arrays (one extra pointer resolution for each row). In fragmented memories, contiguous arrays *might* be faster, in general. The other one is more flexible in the sense that it does not assume fixed lengths in dimensions. So it is dependent on your use case.